# searching something like %ab% in NSArray

Tags: ios, search, nsarray

I want to search my NSArray object for some strings which contain a particular sequence of letters at any position. It should be similar to something like the "LIKE operator" we use in database. For example, I want to search for all the string containing 'ab' in my NSArray object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of `NSString` objects...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"String one", @"String two", @"String three", nil];
for (NSString *string in array)
{
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"XYZ"].location != NSNotFound)
        NSLog (@"Found one: %@", string);            
}
```

[edit]

To add that you can also use the `rangeOfString:options:` method if you need to case insensitive searches amongst others.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter an Array using a [predicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"abs", @"bar", @"foo", @"fabs", nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] 'ab'"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```